# How to find the ICommand binding target (the control)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, command

We use the MVVM pattern. In the View, I have binding the save command to a button:

In the view model, I would like to find out the save command binding target, does it possible?

```
    private Button GetBindingControl(ICommand command)
    {
        // What should I do here:

        return button;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, and it defeats the purpose of MVVM (having the UI logic in the VM regardless of the controls used)

Maybe you could ask instead what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We are doing some migration. There are some actions defined in the original winform user control, the actions signature is like Action<Button, string>. When the save button clicked, it will fire the action with the button itself as its parameter.

Comment: Since we changed it to MVVM now, we implement the button click logic in the view model, and we need to fire the same action. that's why i want to find out the button.

Comment: That's still not the problem you are trying to solve, but an implementation detail based on your previous architecture. What does the Action need the button for?

Answer (score 1):

As @Diego said, this defats the purpose of MVVM because we must try hard not to include visuals or controls in the view models in MVVM...

Having said that there are two options...

1. Using RoutedCommands
2. Using Attached Behaviors.

RoutedCommands are not readily allowed in MVVM as they need to be closely command bound to the UI element i.e. in our case the Button. Hence they too defeat the purpose of MVVM.

But MVVM happily co-exists with the Attached Behaviors.

Many developers shy away from this immensely powerful feature. And we can use it along with RoutedCommands.

In your case

1. Attach to the Button, with a Action delegate.
2. Attach the string object as command parameter.
3. Inside the behavior, set the Button.Command with some Routed command.
4. In the executed event handler, get the button action delegate from the sender / originalsource / source as the button and then call your Action<> accordingly by using `e.Parameter` string value.

Sample code below...

Assume you have common button utilities of signature `Action<Button, string>`

```
public static class ButtonActionUtilities
{
    public static Action<Button, string> ButtonActionDelegate
    {
        get
        {
            return ExecuteButtonClick;
        }
    }

    public static void ExecuteButtonClick(Button btn, string param)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(
          "You clicked button " + btn.Content + " with parameter " + param);
    }
}
```

Then the attched behavior is as below...

```
public static class ButtonAttachedBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ActionDelegateProperty
        = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "ActionDelegate",
            typeof(Action<Button, string>),
            typeof(ButtonAttachedBehavior),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, OnActionDelegatePropertyChanged));

    public static Action<Button, string> GetActionDelegate(
                                            DependencyObject depObj)
    {
        return (Action<Button, string>)depObj.GetValue(
                                            ActionDelegateProperty);
    }

    public static void SetActionDelegate(
         DependencyObject depObj, Action<Button, string> value)
    {
        depObj.SetValue(ActionDelegateProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnActionDelegatePropertyChanged(
        DependencyObject depObj,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (depObj is Button
            && e.NewValue is Action<Button, string>)
        {               
            ((Button)depObj).Command
                = new RoutedCommand(
                        "ActionRoutedCommand",
                         typeof(ButtonAttachedBehavior));
            ((Button) depObj).CommandBindings.Add(
                new CommandBinding(
                    ((Button) depObj).Command,
                    OnActionRoutedCommandExecuted));
        }
    }

    private static void OnActionRoutedCommandExecuted(
       object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var actionDelegate = GetActionDelegate((Button)e.Source);
        actionDelegate((Button) e.Source, (string)e.Parameter);
    }
}
```

And on XAML it will look like this....

```
      <StackPanel>
         <Button x:Name="TestButton" Content="Test Me" 
            local:ButtonAttachedBehavior.ActionDelegate
                ="{x:Static local:ButtonActionUtilities.ButtonActionDelegate}"
            CommandParameter
                ="{Binding Text, ElementName=ParameterTextBox}"/>

          <TextBox x:Name="ParameterTextBox"/>
      </StackPanel>
```

So with the code above you will need to just set the `ActionDelegate` attached property to approapriate delegate and it will execute that.

**I would still suggest you to revamp your existing code setup to separate button specific behaviors to make it more MVVM friendly.**

Comment: I didn't realized that we can pass a object to the command, that's what the CommandParameter useful. I have solved the problem by the following code: <Button Content="Ok" Command="{Binding OKCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />

Comment: But doing it that way would essentially defeat your MVVM :( coz probably your ViewModel (that has the command in it) has referred `System.Windows.Controls` namespace. (correct?)

Comment: @AngleWPF I totally agree with you that it is not the right way to do the MVVM. It's a legacy code. I must make sure all the function works as before and didn't break any thing.